# How to merge the following array?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have the following array and I want to merge it in the center with a slight upward rotation.
[image]

When selecting the merge option from the array modifier, the merge is crooked.
[image]

Is there a way that I can make this merge straight? For context, I'm trying to make this chair wheelbase.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance, you can make it another way:

[image]

Use a cube.

Scale a face.

Extrude individual faces.

Comment: ... or a 5-cylinder?

Comment: Yep, that also work with 5 sided cylinder. Instead of scaling, I just drag the top and bottom face of the middle mesh up, achieving the same look. Thanks both for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think this 'Merge' behaviour of the *Array* modifier qualifies as a bug:

[image]

If you forget that, and follow up the *Array* with a *Weld*:

[image]

.. it appears to behave more sensibly, merging at the *centres* of groups of vertices falling within the threshold. (Empty for illustration only)

If you want to keep everything as non-destructive as you can, that might be an option.